# ASP.NET Forms Authentication plus Basic Authentication

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, rest

So, if you want to make a single page web application, you can set up a website with forms authentication, create accounts, authorize AJAX request, etc with Forms Authentication.  User logs in, browser gets an auth cookie, browser makes an AJAX/JSON request with the auth cookie, server determines I am who I say I am and sends a AJAX/JSON response, and all is right with the world.

Similarly, if I want to make a mobile app, I can set up a rest service.  My rest service uses basic authentication.  User logs in, user gets an Authorization token response header, app sends an Restful/JSON request with an Authorization token request header, server determines I am who I say I am, and sends a Restful/JSON response, and all is right with the world.

But, say I want the same ASP.NET site/code/webconfig to do the same thing with those almost identical requests?  Sounds like it's virtually impossible.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your question about using both Form Authentication and Basic Authentication in same application?

Comment: do you mean you want the website to delegate the authorisation to the REST service?

Comment: Yes, I'd like it to just be both.  I don't want to delegate it, I want it to be a website and a rest service at the same time...  I mean, a rest service is fundamentally just a website responding with JSON.